# How to use composer with a huge codebase?

Tags: php, composer-php

We have a huge code-base (I mean huge, about 2M+ lines) in PHP. I would like to know how you guys managed to integrate composer in this kind of situation.

Specially when the code cannot be decoupled in little projects (Right now) because of the complexity (Even mixed with legacy code) and it's being hold in the same SVN repository.

- Why should I be confident in the quality of the composer/packagist libraries?
- What happens if packagist goes down?
- What should I do if my vendor repository goes down (Github/Bitbucket/Whatever)?
- What happens if some of my vendors decide to delete their library?
- What if they've been hacked and set the next version tag empty?

I know that this possible problems could be over-passed in one way or another. But the fact that the life of a lot people could be depending on this makes me feel a bit crazy with this kind of decision.

What do you think? What are my best options?

Comment: In production, commit the `composer.lock` file.  This will make sure it builds the same versions of every dependency, so you can know it is tested and works.  You will only need to build dependencies when making a new build, so I wouldn't worried about Packagist being down (I've had problems where I couldn't deploy for ~30 minutes because GitHub, Packagist, NPM, etc. were down). You'll be better off with than without it.

Comment: There's also nothing to prevent you from forking your dependencies if they're from public repositories and if you believe that they're likely to be deleted by vendors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point - if you have legacy, 2M+ tighthly-coupled codebase, common open source projects quality shouldn't bother you ;).

For the rest - you can use staging to build your project together with dependencies and then build a full package there (by that I mean all the dependencies downloaded and bundles). Of course you will still be dependent on external packages on your development cycle, but not in deployment/production. Whenever package goes down, you have time and possibility to replace it.

Composer is a really great tool for bundling yor project together with dependencies, so it's both the answer to question "how to use external dependencies" and also to "how to be independent from them", you only need to specify the point, at which you want to bring this independency into your project.

I think that you should develop with external dependencies in mind, lowering your code base as much as possible and not put these problems on your devs shoulders, they want to use code, libraries, play with tiem... then, somewhere in your deployment process, bundle it all together (staging is a good place). Even if your dependencies will disappear and you will have to spend your development time to replace them:

It will probably still cost you less than handling all on your own.

Comment: Thanks for this answer I managed to get some kind of middle-point where I intend to use composer from a private repo (Satis) wich has an option to cache external libraries.